# Mounting obb file on Galaxy Tab / Android 4.1.2 not working; working fine with Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, galaxy-tab, apk-expansion-files

I try to mount an (unencrypted) obb file (APK expansion file).

The following code is working fine on Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.4. 
The obb file gets mounted and the OnObbStateChangeListener is entered as well, I can see the log lines in the log.

However, **on Samsung Galax Tab 2 (with Android 4.1.2) it does not work**. "Start mounting" is being logged, but then OnObbStateChangeListener is never entered, but also, no error or any other related info is shown in the log.

```
final StorageManager sm = (StorageManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE);

Log.d(TAG, "Start mounting " );

sm.mountObb(
    new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Android/obb/com.matheapp.www.matheapp2/main.2.com.matheapp.www.matheapp2.obb").getAbsolutePath(),    
    new OnObbStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onObbStateChange(String path, int state) {
            super.onObbStateChange(path, state);
            Log.d(TAG, "onObbStateChange: Path: " + path);
            Log.d(TAG, "onObbStateChange: State: " + state);            
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been working in this and we didn't find any solution, so instead we are using a zip file renamed to .obb instead of a normal obb created with `jobb`. That solution works in every device we've tested so far, even in the Galaxy Tab with Android 4.1.2

Hopes this works on your app also.

Answer (score 1):

I've run across this problem myself on some devices; this could also be due to a bug in android:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61881

It seems that the only thing to do is start using AssetFileDescriptors and offsets (for audio/video) or inputstreams. In my case I can't use any of these as I need a String/filepath, so I think I'm going to be forced to unzip the expansion file somewhere.

Comment: I've saw that issue but is for Android 4.4, not 4.1.2. Also you can read the .zip without decompressing anything, just use an uncompressed zip file and read the data